# How to use DispatchGroup in a loop with order?

Tags: swift, loops

I want to get data saved in order like

Data saved 0 
Data saved 1 
Data saved 2 
....

But the actual output is like :
-Data saved 4 
-Data saved 0 
-Data saved 2 
-Data saved 3 
-Data saved 1

How can i fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance

```
var anArray : [String] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/070091.jpg")
    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/070092.jpg")
    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/077111.jpg")
    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/077112.jpg")
    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/077113.jpg")
    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/077115.jpg")
    anArray.append("profilFotograflari/079999.jpg")

    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for i in 0 ..< 5 {

        myGroup.enter()
        let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\(anArray[i])")

        pathReference.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("An error has occured!")
            } else {
                print("Data saved \(i)")
                myGroup.leave()

            }

        }

    }

    myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Finished all requests.")
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, forcing it to go in order (i.e. waiting for one to finish before starting next) can make it go slower. Do you really need to do that? And what exactly is `getData` doing? Uploading? Downloading? Just processing image? You don’t appear to be doing anything with the resulting `data`, so it’s not clear what you’re doing. The nature of the solution will depend a bit upon what you’re doing inside `getData`. And I’m not understanding the seven image names, but looping through `0 ..< 5`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rob's comment that you probably don't want to do this unless you really have to because it will slow down the saving process. If you NEED to have them go in order and you really want to use `DispatchGroup` to do it, you could do the following:

```swift
let group = DispatchGroup()

for i in 0 ..< 5 {
    group.enter()
    asyncTask { // Use your getData function here
        print("Done: \(i)")
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()
}
```

I would also note that in your code:

> ```swift
> if let error = error {
>    print("An error has occured!")
> } else {
>    print("Data saved \(i)")
>    myGroup.leave()
> }
> ```

If there is an error, 'leave' will not get called and you will never be notified of completion. You should probably `leave` even if there is an error so that your program doesn't hang.

Comment: Obviously, if you use `group.wait`, don’t call that from the main queue. Dispatch the whole loop to some global queue. And if you’re going to wait at each iteration, I might replace dispatch group with dispatch semaphore, because we’re no longer dealing with “group” of tasks...